# Using HTML5 input types and jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, html

I have a form with the following field(this field is just one of 4)

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="30" class="text-input" />
```

If I use this in jquery the form works as expected:

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message + '&ip=' + ip + '&date=' + date;
```

However if I use this to shorten the code, the email input is totally ignored on submit.

```
var dataString = $('#contact').serialize();
```

Is this a bug or is there something Im not seeing. What is the difference between the two?  If I change the email input to "text" then the form works with serialize

Using jquery 1.6.0

Comment: What is the value of `dataString` after `$('#contact').serialize();`? How does it compare to the manually-created string?

Comment: George the values are all correct except it leaves the email value out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue recently, and it turned out I was using jQuery 1.3.2!

Upgrading to 1.6.2 (latest) fixed it.

I suspect this later version upgraded the serialize function to recognise the new HTML5 input types.

Comment: You're correct that it was fixed, but it was updated [back in jQuery 1.4](https://github.com/dmethvin/jquery/commit/9719f2235fd382c0c7a00b69c282f56e0c087847), so being on 1.6.0 this *should* work for the OP.

Comment: Which of course shows why it fixed my code of course but not the OP. Worth trying 1.6.2 I guess, although from what you're saying it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Good point, I will update.  Thanks for the discussion fellas.  I am trying to use all the html5 elements where I can.